# Ubuntu resets UEFI boot order every time I use Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04

I have 2 hard drives in my machine. One has Windows and the other has Ubuntu. I use UEFI/BIOS to choose between drives, and consequently between OSes, to boot from. Whenever I use Windows, the boot order remains the same between reboots. However, Ubuntu always places itself on the top of the boot list whenever I use it and that changes the default OS.

Is there a way to prevent Ubuntu from changing this order? I remember that it didn't do that originally but I started doing that at some point and I can't figure out what changed. I don't have GRUB or any other boot loader. Also putting a password on the BIOS setup would be cumbersome because I change back and forth quite a lot between OSes. I'm currently using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Do you mean the boot order in GRUB or the boot order for your BIOS? If the latter, you will have to consult with the documentation for your device's motherboard- it's not related to any OS.  FYI: Ubuntu *should* be first here, otherwise you will not be able to choose OS since the Windows bootloader can't boot Ubuntu

Comment: Ubuntu is not asserting itself- your BIOS is simply booting from the option you chose last.

Comment: I'm referring to the BIOS boot order. I believe Ubuntu might have something to do with this issue because Ubuntu is still the first choice when I boot from Windows and then start the machine again. So I don't think the BIOS is merely booting from my last choice. If that was the case, Windows should be the default OS after rebooting from Windows.

Comment: The recommended dual boot configuration is that you use GRUB as the bootloader. Know that even when using GRUB, it doesn't change anything with the Windows bootloader. It hands off to the Windows bootloader when Windows is selected. You have made the choice to use your BIOS for this purpose, so you will have to figure out what behaviors you can control with your BIOS settings.  Nothing you've mentioned here would suggest that Ubuntu has anything to do with your issue.  Everything points to your BIOS.

Comment: Are both UEFI installs? You could be switching boot mode and then that default stays. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: In my experience, when a new version of grub is going to be installed during an upgrade, grub-install will recreate boot menu entry and sets itself to the first place in boot-order.